# Problem of functional completeness in Delft's book "Foundations of Computation"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am currently reading [this book on mathematical logic from Delft University](https://textbooks.open.tudelft.nl/textbooks/catalog/view/53/144/370-1) (I have to admit that I am disappointed with the quality of the book). I don't understand some things from the book. For example, at the end of the second chapter (page 18) there is problem 10. which says:

> For our proof that {¬,∨} is functionally complete, we need to show
> that all formulas in propositional logic can be expressed in an
> equivalent form using only {¬, ∧, ∨, →, ↔}.
>
> a) How many unique truth tables exist for formulas containing two
> atoms?
>
> b) Create a function for each of the possible truth tables that uses
> only the 5 operators listed above.
>
> c) Give an (informal) argument why this means all formulas in
> propositional logic can be expressed using only these five operators.

Without going into the fact that the author did not define anywhere in the book before this problem what a formula of propositional logic actually is (so it is unclear what we actually need to show), I, (confused) go to the end of the book (page 188), where the author gives a "solution" to this problem, where first in parts a) and b) it is shown that, if we have only two variables, each table from the set of 2^4 = 16 possible truth tables can be represented using some formula consisting solely of two atoms and logical operations from the set {¬, ∧, ∨, →, ↔}.

But now, for the proof of c), the author writes:

> Given that we can create a formula for each of the possible truth
> table using these 5 operators. Furthermore, we know that there are
> only 2^(2^n) possible truth tables, where n is the number of unique
> atoms. Given that every one of these truth tables has a corresponding
> formula using only the 5 operators, which we denote as f_i, where 1 ≤
> i ≤ 2^(2^n) − 1. Now take a formula, f′, that uses the same unique
> atoms, but not necessarily the same operators from the set of 5
> operators stated in the description. The truth table for the formula
> f′ will be equal to one of the 2^2^n possible truth tables, which also
> means that there is a f_i that is equivalent to f′, so we can rewrite
> f′

And while parts a) and b) are clear to me, the argument the author used in the proof of c) is not clear to me at all. Can someone explain to me what the author is trying to say there? The part where it says *"Given that every one of these truth tables has a corresponding formula using only the 5 operators..."* is particularly unclear to me. Isn't that exactly what we have to prove? Please, help - I'm really confused!

Comment: For an overview of the issue, see [Functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness)

Comment: @Mauro, I understand what Functional completeness is (more or less). It's just that I don't understand this particular proof from the Delft's book. That's why I'm asking here if someone can explain it to me.

Comment: @Mauro, that part is clear to me (parts a) and b) from the proof are clear to me. Please, see the solution in the book). It's the proof from part c) that confuses me

Comment: Also, it's clear to me that if we have n variables, that truth table has 2^(2^n) rows. That's not the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146232/discussion-between-xenax-and-mauro-allegranza).

Comment: "if we have n
 atoms the truth table has 2^n
 rows. 2^(2^n) is the total number of possible TT." Yes, that's what I meant actually, but I wrote it wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Having said that, YES you are right: the point "Given that every one of these truth tables has a corresponding formula using only the 5 operators..." is exactly what you have to prove. The formal answer is CNF.

Comment: I think that the ‘Given …’ at the start of the proof of c) refers to what was just shown in b).  But I agree that the proof of c) here is rather cryptic

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*. You are right.

The point

> "Given that every one of these truth tables has a corresponding formula using only the 5 operators..."

is exactly what you have to prove.

The "formal" answer is [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form): "every propositional formula can be converted into an equivalent formula that is in CNF. This transformation is based on rules about logical equivalences: double negation elimination, De Morgan's laws, and the distributive law."

What we can do with the hint in the textbook: it is a sort of intuitive approach to an inductive proof.

The author shows (writing it in full) that there is a solution to the two atoms case: "we can create a formula for each of the [$2^{2^2}$] possible truth table using the [basic] 5 operators."

The claim for the general case [$2^{2^n}$] can be inductively proved considering that we can split the truth table in two parts: one with the atoms $p_1, \ldots, p_{n-1}$ and a second one for the atom $p_n$.

But if we assume (induction hypotheses) that we can solve the problem for the case with $(n-1)$ atoms, then we have reduced the problem to the two atoms case.

Comment: Well done, Mauro! This has to be it! Only, in that case, the author wrote it very vaguely and it is not at all clear (even after the tenth reading) that it is an inductive proof.